# sqlite throwing a "String not recognized as a valid datetime"

Tags: c#, .net, database, sqlite, datetime-format

I am playing around with Sqlite and keep getting an error when trying to read back some test data. For example, I created a simple db with a single table and some columns and populated it with some test data as shown below.

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE "shows"(id integer primary key asc autoincrement, showName TEXT, guest TEXT, dateAired date, dateWatched date);

sqlite> select * from shows;
6|test show|test guest 1|2012.05.01|2012.07.10
7|test show|test guest 2|2012.05.02|2012.07.10
8|test show|test guest 4|2012.05.04|2012.07.10
```

I am using the System.Data.Sqlite library available [here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) , but it keeps giving me an error while trying to read the date column. I tried putting the dates in the dd-MM-yyyy format, but still get an error saying "String Not Recognized as a valid datetime." I have tried using DateTime.Parse or casting it to datetime or just ToString()'ing it to see what happens, but I keep getting the same error. I can read the text fields fine, but can't read the date fields.

My C# code snipped is given below

```
var sqliteConn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=data/shows.db;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True");
sqliteConn.Open();
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sqliteConn);
cmd.CommandText = "select * from shows";

SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader( );
while (reader.Read( ))
    {
    var showName = reader["showName"];
    // This is where it keeps giving me an error.
    // I have tried various things such as DateTime.Parse
    var airedDate = DateTime.ParseExact("yyyy.MM.dd", reader["dateAired"].ToString(), new CultureInfo("en-AU"));
     }
reader.Close( );
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 32):

Based on the discussion in [this thread](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/info/f4db9f273a), I decided to construct my connection string with the "datetimeformat" parameter and the "String Not Recognized as a valid datetime" issue was resolved.

My example connection string:

```
source=<source to db file>;version=3;new=False;datetimeformat=CurrentCulture
```

This feature was released in version 1.0.87.0 on July 8, 2013 (see [release notes](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/news.wiki))

Comment: I think there are a bug in C# SQlite wrapper, the default datetimeformat is ISO8601, but forcing to CurrentCulture work great.

Comment: Which version of system.data.sqlite are you using, i tried th CurrentCulture, e but i get an error `Requested value 'CurrentCulture' was not found.`

Comment: `CurrentCulture` didn't work for me. `Ticks` solved the problem.

Comment: @erichoxworth With your additional parameter, I get this issue mostly resolved. The only problem are some strange contents like "\N" instead of real date. I found no other solution then TRY...CATCH around it.

Answer (score 10):

This thread might be a bit old but I came across the same problem and found a "solution".

It seems that System.Data.SQLite does not handle `DateTime`s correctly. I tried `DateTime.ParseExact` and gave the format in my database (mm/dd/yyyy) but I noticed that it threw an error when just calling `ToString()` on the `DataReader` column for the date. This seemed strange since I was not attempting to fit it into a `Date` but have it read out as a `String`.

Because of this, I went back to the view I was calling from the database and wrapped all of my dates in a `CAST as nvarchar(10)`. This way, the database will return strings and not dates. Now, the `DateTime.Parse` works just fine!

I'll use a trigger on the view to pull the string/date back in and insert/update the underlying tables, thus having all the conversions happen in the database, instead of System.Data.SQLite.

There is a new version of System.Data.SQLite coming sometime in December of 2012, I hope this is addressed!

Comment: thanks , i had the same problem , it solved the error

Comment: Do SQLite addressed this issue? I can't change DB's DateTime format so the problem still resides. When a user changes the date time format on Windows OS my app crashes. :( my SQLite version is 3.15.1.0 and im developing a Windows 8.1 store app.) Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
select strftime('%m/%d/%Y',substr(colName,0,20)) from tablename
```

This will work, I have tested this, because built in functions in sqlite converts string to datetime format

Answer (score 1):

Changing the string for connection didn't work for me but the trigger idea help me use it this way

`"Select Cast("Coulname" as nvarchar(20)) From "Table Name"`

Answer (score -2):

> Error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Change your system date time format to you database fild datetime format.

i hope it help you....