# SELECT datetime as string in sqlite not behaving as documentation suggests

Tags: c#, sqlite, datetime

consider the following SQL in SQLITE

```
CREATE TABLE filemeta (filemeta_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, localLastModified DATETIME)
```

now explain why these don't work properly ?

```
select datetime(localLastModified,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS") AS localLastModified from filemeta
select datetime(localLastModified) from filemeta
```

but this ***does*** work (until I use it in C#, when it doesn't work if `null` due to a [known bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11414399/sqlite-throwing-a-string-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime))

```
select localLastModified from filemeta
```

Comment: can u add some examples in ur question?

Comment: ? other than the examples ?

Comment: What documentation says that there is a data type named [DATETIME](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime), or that the [datetime function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) can be used with a format string?

Comment: fist of all sqlite "works" with a DATETIME artifact datatype despite there being none. it uses TEXT for everything (rubbish idea) but you forget that I told you the 3rd one works.. oh well