# Reading a Unix epoch time from a SQLite DB with ADO.NET System.Data.SQLite

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, ado.net, datetime-format

While I'm reading a complete data table with the **Fill()** method of **SQLiteDataAdapter** I get a “String not recognized as a valid datetime” exception.

The exception is thrown while reading a column of type `DATETIME NOT NULL` which contains Unix epoch time stamps in milliseconds. And yes I know that there is no specific DateTime type in SQLite.
I know (from [sqlite throwing a "String not recognized as a valid datetime"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11414399/sqlite-throwing-a-string-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime)) that I can adapt the ConnectionString and set "DateTimeFormat=UnixEpoch".
 But this setting interprets the value as seconds **not** milliseconds since January 1, 1970.
Using it anyway results in a `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.
There is another parameter for the connection string: `DateTimeFormatString`. But I don't see a way to use it with my format.

I cannot change the data in the table. And I also don't want to enumerate the columns manually.
Is there a simple way to get the table filled with "select * from ..."? Also just reading it as string would be helpful.
There is a workouround with "DateTimeFormat=Ticks" but this is an ugly solution because it is **not** based on January 1, 1970.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards

I stripped down my code to a minimalistic example to demonstrate the behavior.

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SQLite;

namespace SQLite
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            //using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=d:\src\C#\SQLite\SQLite\db\sampledb.db; DateTimeFormat=Ticks;"))
            using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=d:\src\C#\SQLite\SQLite\db\sampledb.db; DateTimeFormat=UnixEpoch;"))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var sqlDataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM TimeStamps;", connection))
                {
                    var dataTable = new DataTable();
                    sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also the the DB now just contains one table. Both dates i.e. 1586948400000 are in Year 2020.
[image: Table in sample DB]

The code above produces an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.
If the code is executed with `DateTimeFormat=Ticks` in the ConnectionString it runs but creates the wrong calendar dates.

The table was created with this SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE "TimeStamps" (
    "Id"    INTEGER,
    "TimeStamps"    DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY("Id")
)
```

Comment: Can you just change the type in your DataTable to be an Int64, and then apply a conversion wherever you *use* the column? That would probably be the simplest approach.

Comment: If you're using a strongly typed DataTable, you could have a property for the "raw" value and a delegating property that performs the conversion for you. If you could provide more context, we could probably help you more.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me @Jon Skeet.
The database has been created with the help of [flyway](https://flywaydb.org/).
I get these databases from customers. In an early version of the SW the data in the column was entered as a localized date i.e. "15.04.2019". Later versions were using the ms Unix timestamps. My code has to deal with both kinds. I have no problem to read the localized dates.

Comment: At the moment we don't know what your code looks like at all, which makes it much harder to help you. We know that you're using `SQLiteDataAdapter`, but we don't know how you're setting things up to call `Fill`. Ideally, you'd give the data adapter the appropriate schema depending on what the table has at execution time, and then perform a suitable conversion where required.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: In the meantime I provided the code you asked for. It would be nice if you could point me to right direction. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Right - I'm slightly surprised to see DATETIME as a valid column type given the lack of real support for it in SQLite, but never mind. I haven't used this aspect of ADO.NET for years, but I *suspect* if you populate the `TimeStamps` column in your DataTable yourself, specifying a suitable integer data type, that *might* avoid the data adapter trying to do the conversion for you.